# Combining the Same Terms in different Vocabulary as one

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have two vocabulary used by two different content type.

1. Category
2. Tags

However, the second content type does not use the Vocabulary Category. But there are nodes in second content type that has been tagged with same name in Category. So now I want to have the nodes of these same name be displayed as one.

That is 
Category has term - TermA
Tags has term - Term A

Node of Type1 has been associated with TermA of Category and Node of Type2 has been tagged with TermA of Tags, but both these nodes should appear in one single taxonomy page as TermA. I am using Taxonomy Term Views.

How can this be done any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should try putting both Category and Tags under a single master vocabulary. Then assign both `Category` and `Tags` as parents of the shared term. So you have:

- Level 1: `MasterVocabulary`
- Level 2: `Category [parent:MasterVocabulary]`, `Tags [parent:MasterVocabulary]`
- Level 3: `SharedTermA [parents:Category, Tags]`, `TermB [parent:Category], ...`

Comment: Interesting alternative :)

Comment: Both the vocabulary exists for the first content type while only the tag is for the second content type. Now the Tags vocabulary is referenced via autocomplete term widget(tagging) widget, which I will not be able to use it using the above approach.

Comment: Instead of pulling your hair out to make it work maybe you should rethink the way you structure things on your site to accommodate logic that can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if it allows merging terms in different vocabularies, you could try

[Term Merge](https://drupal.org/project/term_merge)

It allows merging terms via the admin taxonomy user interface.

Comment: The duplicate term name occurs because the second content type does not have the Category vocabulary. If I do add the Category vocabulary in the second one, I do not have a way to put them in one text field. So merging is not an option.